# How did the Iron Islanders manage to set fire to Winterfell and flee?

Tags: game-of-thrones

If Theon Greyjoy and his men, all 20 of them, were besieged in Winterfell and surrounded by 500 enemy men, how were they able to set fire to Winterfell and flee? Wouldn't the 500 prevent them from burning and fleeing Winterfell with an unconscious Theon?

Answer (score 15):

In regards to the TV series, this is not known yet.

However, in the books this is what happened (MAJOR SPOILERS AHEAD):

.

.

I'M  NOT KIDDING. SUPER MAJOR SPOILERS FOR NON BOOK READERS.

.

.

> Winterfell was sacked by the forces of the Bastard of Bolton. When the ironborn surrender, Ramsay Snow (Roose Bolton's bastard) slaughters the soldiers and captures Theon.

**EDIT:**

The events in the show with regards to this have now been shown to be the same as the book's.

Comment: Having not seen the second season of the TV show, but read a number of questions and answers about it, do the Boltons even exist in that version of the world?

Comment: @MichaelEdenfield - We haven't seen Reek yet in the TV series (if he even exists). Perhaps you mean the character played by Ralph Inneson (Finchy of "The Office")? If so, that's Dagmar Cleftjaw.

Comment: I think we will see him. First, the story arc involving Reek is a major part of the later books, and second, he has _already been mentioned_ in the show. He is the bastard Roose Bolton referred to.

Comment: @AndresF. - Oh I'm sure we'll see Ramsay, but not so sure we'll see him as Reek though.

Answer (score 9):

The outcome in the show is different from the books (read @SystemDown's spoilers for dtails), so we can't know for sure what happened unless they revisit it next season. That seems likely, given that Theon's storyline in the novels continues for quite a while yet. (In particular, we don't *know* that they got away clean...)

But just to answer the general question:

> Would it be possible for a tiny force of ~20 poorly-disiplined men to raze and escape from Winterfell in the face of a much larger force of ~500 well-armed soliders?

For a hold as large as Winterfell (estimated at ~80 acres),  500 men is really not much of a siege force; of course, they outnumbered Theon's man 25:1, but those odds would have mostly come into effect once Winterfell was breached and combat began. That many men would likely not be able to effectively guard all three gates (two on opposite sides of the hold) and still present an imposing threat to Theon. That doesn't even count whatever smaller exits from the hold exist -- Maester Luwin admitted openly that such exist.

If Theon's forces had no desire to retreat calmly, or to try and hold Winterfell, then they easily could have accomplished what they wanted. By setting fire to the hold, they would have caused panic and chaos for the forces coming into the hold.  They would need to stop and restore order before they could worry about tracking down the escaping enemy. This is particularly true if the larger force had more invested in Winterfell than the smaller -- they'd definitely prefer to safe Winterfell's residents over killing a tiny, failed fleeing invader. Set fire to the front of the hold, then retreat out the back gate while everyone was distracted.

Keep in mind, the smaller a force the easier it is to *avoid* a larger force, especially if you're literally running away from them. If two equally large ~500-men forces were to meet in combat, it wouldn't be at all unreasonable to think that 20 or so of the losing side managed to escape with their wounded. Maester Luwin seemed to think Theon could (possibly) accomplish this task without burning Winterfell down, so it seems reasonable that a small force could accomplish it, given the appropriate distraction.

Comment: I think you make some inaccurate assumptions about the relevance being outnumbered, especially in a large hold. The 500 could split 100 to each gate (outnumbering all of Theon's men 5 to 1 at each gate) and still have 200 men to spy along the walls for escapees.

Comment: You're probably right about the numbers being enough for a siege -- 100 men-per-gate could probably keep Theon in. I'm not so sure about the wall watchers. Winterfell is *huge*. If it were square, it would have almost a mile and a half of walls to watch, including the walls right up against the wolfswood. Add in that the fire will start a panic and probably draw troops away from the gates/walls, and I think the escape is at least feasible.

Comment: I'll grant you feasible...however 1.5 miles of walls per 200 people is 7920ft / 200 people = 39.6 feet per person, not that unreasonable to be able to watch. I still agree it is feasible :), though having read the books it is really a moot point.

Answer (score 0):

Ramsey and the 500 are the ones who burned winterfell not the 20 iron islanders. They surrendered and left theon for Ramsey as an agreement because rob stark said if they surrender they would not be hurt as long as they gave up theon.

Answer (score 0):

As for **setting the fire, in the TV show, it is not clear who burned Winterfell.** It could be Ironborn or Boltons. They address it in several conversations: dying maester Luwin with kids, ...

> Roose Bolton with Walder Frey, etc.

but they never make clear who did it. Since ...

> Boltons were repairing Winterfell later,

it seems more likely that Ironborn did it.

As for **fleeing**, ...

> ... they did not flee. The "enemy men" (Boltons) offered them safe passage home if they give up Theon. They did, but the Boltons killed them anyway.